# Submit PHP code when user check a checkbox

Tags: php, button, ftp

I have the following code for an on off button with nice looking css style

```
<?php
$wifi2g=file_get_contents("wifi2g.txt");
$wifi2g= trim ($wifi2g);
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" <?php if ($wifi2g == "enabled") {echo "checked";} ?>>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

I can read as you see from wifi2g.txt and  define the button position on or off (checked or unchecked). I have two scripts that i want to upload to ftp server wifion.php and wifioff.php. These scripts depends from button position. When user sets button position to ON (or checked) i want to upload the wifion.php and when set to off or unchecked to upload wifioff.php. How can i make this work? I found this button here https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/

Comment: You have to use Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you is familiar with Jquery, you can do this

```
$('.onoffswitch-checkbox').on('change',function(){
    var input = $(this);

    if(input.prop('checked') == true){
       input.closest('form').submit();
    }
});
```

or if you want to continue in same page, use ajax

```
$('.onoffswitch-checkbox').on('change',function(){
    var input = $(this);

    if(input.prop('checked') == true){
         $.ajax({
              url:'test.php'
              ,type:'POST'
              ,data: {btn:'was checked!'}
         }).done(function(data){
             // do something with returning of php
         });
    }
});
```

Comment: The question says to submit to `wifion.php` or `wifioff.php` depending on the state of the checkbox. Where is that in your code?[

Comment: it's another file wifion.php. In this case after submiting button change example.button set to on, php script will be to ftp upload a file to remote location. and when button set to off i have to upload again but different file